# Math newbie: what to read?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

Quick question for you all: what should a high school senior who intends to major in CS and math read to become familiar with proofs, calc, algorithms, etc?

I know that's incredibly broad, basically I'm just looking for any book that could be of use to me, because I am severely undereducated in math. I'm not bad at HS math, I get good grades, and I'm a fast learner, but I haven't had access beyond pre-cal and AP Stats, so I'm severely lacking (no trig, no calc, but I got into purdue!)

Any advice for me? I really need to learn this stuff, and I really want to. Thanks!

Edit: this question is on hold due to its opinion-based nature, so I'll try to edit and clarify a bit. Rather than suggesting the absolute best books for me to read and absolutely study, could you just tell me some books that were helpful to you and your understanding of high-level math? I don't know if that fits the format any better, but it should discourage any arguments over opinion.

Comment: No trig and no calc? Well there you go...

Comment: Learn trig and calc, and then read Spivak's Calculus.

Comment: I do plan on learning trig and calc, obviously, I would just like to self-study a bit before I'm having it thrown at me by a grad student in a lecture hall next year. Will Stewart's or Spivak's calculus help me learn any of this or should I pick up some books specifically for trig? Thanks.

Comment: If you are looking for an introduction to the basic methods of proof, may I humbly suggest the tutorial that comes with my proof software available free at my website http://www.dcproof.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that number theory and group theory are two subjects that are easy enough to understand with no prior knowledge and most importantly are very good for learning styles in proof writing.

Two good books.

Friendly Intro To Number Theory Silverman ISBN 9780321816191 Edition 4

Book Of Abstract Algebra Pinter ISBN 9780486474175 Edition 2

I hope this helps.

Comment: I would start with sets - set theory is really the cornerstone of all interesting mathematics, including both number theory and groups. Many classic texts start out with a "refresher" on the subject, I suggest Rosenbloom's Introduction to Mathematical Logic, which begins with a pretty quick overview of the fundamentals. (and it also has some good stuff on mathematical logic... :) )

Comment: Thank you! I have self studied some information theory and number theory, so picking up a comprehensive book about it sounds like the next good step.

Answer (score 3):

You need to learn trigonometry to understand calculus. You need to learn calculus to understand the set $\mathbb{R^n}$ and its properties. You need to learn those properties to prove things.

Pick up a Stewart's calculus book and begin there.

Oh yeah, and don't get frustrated if it takes you over three hours to understand a concept. That's uncommon, but it's more common to spend days on a concept. :)

Comment: Downvoter: Care to comment?

Comment: I didn't downvote but you don't necessarily need calculus to understand $\mathbb R^n$...

Comment: Also suggesting "picking up" a $150 book which is designed for classes designed to cut out students is something people might not be so happy with.

Comment: Well, I took that route and enjoyed it. At that level I did not care much about the proofs. For example, I didn't really know what FTC was until a week ago.

Comment: Thanks, I will see if I can get my hands on a copy. I work, so I'm not against the concept of buying an expensive textbook by any means, I just hope I can use it right!

Answer (score 3):

One very important subject of mathematics you must learn is Linear Algebra. Calculus is a **MUST** because it is the foundation for computation. I recommend [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521675995) book because a provides you a structured foundation for proof strategy. It is one that all higher mathematicians (even me) have read.

So, the path that I recommend to you is finish trigonometry, then Calculus, then get into Basic Set Theory, do [Real and Complex Analysis](http://ruangbacafmipa.staff.ub.ac.id/files/2012/02/Real-and-Complex-Analysis-by-Walter-Rudin.pdf) with [Multivariable Calculus](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/211/vcalc.pdf), then do [Linear Algebra](http://www.math.byu.edu/klkuttle/linearalgebra.pdf). Once you have done that, you will have a VERY strong foundation. With a better foundation, your comprehension of concepts will come easier to you.

Let me know if you need anything else.

P.s., Congrats on getting into Purdue!

Comment: Can I please get a reason for why I got a downvote?

Comment: I did not do it, but the question asks for some book suggestions. Maybe edit a few in?

Comment: Thank you for the subject suggestions, I will definitely try to advance in that order. Thank you!

Comment: I don't agree with you that you should study real and complex analysis with multivariable calculus. Rather, you should study multivariable first, then linear algebra, then real analysis, then complex analysis. This way of studying is bound to be very confusing, leading to some sorta deep misunderstandings, and @Riley, I hope you heed my advice as well.

Comment: @ring so your approach would build fundamentals easier? I'll consider this, thanks.

Comment: @Riley It will give you the foundations, yes, for studying any higher mathematics that you may choose to study, like topology and abstract algebra (which you should read _only_ after reading the subjects in the order that I wrote in the above comment).

Comment: @ring thank you, once I start digging in I will definitely arrange them like that. I've created a book list on Amazon and I think I'm picking up a few at my local HPB soon, and I'll be studying from now until I start my math major next fall (and then I'll be double-ly studying!)

Comment: @Riley Hey, why don't you shoot me an email with your book list? I can also recommend you some books which I found interesting when I was studying this stuff. (My email is on my nlab page, which you can access by going to my profile page.)

Answer (score 2):

You should read Martin Gardner's books more than anything I think.  They'll motivate you to learn mathematics far more than a standard text in some subject like trigonometry or basic calculus. Check out [http://www.amazon.com/Colossal-Book-Mathematics-Paradoxes-Problems/dp/0393020231/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1419142855&sr=1-1&keywords=martin+gardner+math](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393020231) for instance.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to check out some of the books above, but I will check this out as well.